# Network error in axios react native for android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Hi  i am writing a get call using axios in react native.

when i directly call the below api which is deployed in aws server iam getting network error.

`https://test.co.in/test/fetchAppFlags/mobilenumber`

But when  iam calling the api which is in local server and run by ngrok i am getting the response.

`https://9929cda57b85.ngrok.io/test/fetchAppFlags/mobilenumber`

After the above call when change my api call to aws api i am getting the response.

`https://test.co.in/test/fetchAppFlags/mobilenumber`

Is there any thing wrong in the front end while making api call or server configuration side.

Thank you.

Comment: It may be from server side. Check browser console logs. Are there any error logs?

Comment: are you behind a proxy? Try to run from a physical device if you are currently using an emulator

Comment: Hi @user10384449 i am already running the app in a physical device.